# PWA run offline

Tags: https, progressive-web-apps, offline, offlineapps

I'm trying to build a PWA which should run offline.

My service worker:

```
self.addEventListener("install", function (event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open("sw-cache").then(function (cache) {
      return cache.add("index.html");
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener("fetch", function (event) {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request).then(function (response) {
      return response || fetch(event.request);
    })
  );
});
```

1. If I run LiveServer in VSCode i can install my PWA in Edge and in Chrome. (https://http://127.0.0.1:5500/), but my PWA is only available if the server is running.
2. If I try to install it locally i without any server I get `TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The URL protocol of the current origin ('null') is not supported.`

I read somewhere that a PWA or the service worker needs a https something to run?
How can i run a PWA offline?
Is this even possible, or do i need Electron, Android or IOs App?

Answer (score 0):

First i forgot to cache my files but this:
https://medium.com/dev-channel/learn-how-to-build-a-pwa-in-under-5-minutes-c860ad406ed help a lot, but to answer my question the best i could find was a comment on reddit which says:

'PWAs are fancy browser Tabs.' and thats true,

i would add: They are linked to your browsers cache and storage, so if you cleanup browser cache on closing, your PWA data is also gone and you need to recache.

If you have a website and want more traffic, PWA is maybe a good idea, but if you want to build an app, without going Hybride or Native, cause you think PWA is a workaround, maybe not.

Feel free to correct me, if i didn't got it right.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple to build a responsive website and convert to PWA using tools like PWABUILDER. And if you set it up with caching options and the website is static content, it's going to work offline well.

Hope this helps.